# Pandas groupby order keeps changing (< Python 3.6)

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a different order of columns, every time I restart my kernel and run this `pd.groupby`:

`df.groupby(['code', 'code_description']).agg({'col_A': ['count', 'sum'], 'col_B': 'sum', 'col_C': 'sum', 'col_D': 'sum'})`

Sometimes it's aggregated `col_A` statistics first, sometimes `B` or `C`. Since this order keeps changing, I cannot standardize my reports. Anyone knows why? I've tried resetting the index after the groupby, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered in all versions of python.  The order of arguments to `agg` is probably not being maintained.  Either index your columns in the proper order after the aggregation, or pass an `OrderedDict` if you are on Python < 3.6

Comment: The duplicate I linked is for a fairly old version of `pandas`, but I tested it out and it still works for me in `0.24.3`

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful. I am using Python 3.5, so I'll use an 'OrderedDict'. Asking this question allowed me to learn that as of Python 3.6, dictionaries are insertion ordered. So I'm glad I asked!

Comment: Good to hear! Dictionaries being insertion ordered in Python 3.6 is an implementation detail found in the CPython implementation.  It became a guarantee in Python 3.7